# HealPix / Healpy: Creat healpix map from (MODIS) satellite data

Tags: healpy

I’m planing to map satellite data from MODIS onto a sphere and I thought Healpix could be the right way to do it. However, I don't know how to go about it:

Does the input map need to be in FITS format or could I read an HDF4 MODIS data file into an array (with python) and then use healpy to map it onto a sphere?

I came across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495134/7157742 and hoped that something similar would be possible in my case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a standard `numpy` array.

You need to map your data into the right HEALPix pixel.
To do so you can get arrays of colatitude `theta` and longitude `phi` of your data and then find to which pixel they map to using `hp.ang2pix`.

Then you can create a 1D array `healpy` map and work with it.

See an example Jupyter Notebook https://gist.github.com/zonca/680c68c3d60697eb0cb669cf1b41c324